# Writing JSON file in chunks

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have 2 dictionaries, first one has a metadata about one object, this first object has mappings which can be "n" numbers.

The mappings also has lot of data associated with it, I would like to create a JSON and write it to JSON file in python.

The problem is, the mappings can be many and holding them in memory till they are written to file could be memory intensive and can run out of memory.

The JSON looks like,

```json
{
"title": "sample one",
"id": 1,
"mappings": [

{
"mapped_data":"data"
},
{
"mapped_data":"data"
}
]

}
```

Before writing to the file, if I need to hold all this into dictionary and then convert it to JSON and write to file would be very memory intensive. I would like to know how I can achieve it.

I very much appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45143995/2570277

Comment: I might think about creating a `data_mappings.json` file based on the [json lines format](https://jsonlines.org/)